# with it, outside control

Tags: ellipsis, subordinate-clauses

"If the press were not profit-making, who would support it? The only alternative is subsidy and, **with it, outside control.**"

Q1. I understand the sentence until "subsidy and", but not the following part. What does that bold part mean?

Q2. Is that bold part grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence

> The only alternative is subsidy and, with it, outside control.

is correct and understandable

The fragment

> with it, outside control.
>   *with subsidies, there will be outside control*

is a subordinate clause which needs additional context to make sense.

The "it" refers to subsidies, what the sentence is saying is that whoever subsidizes the press will control what is reported (*outside control*).